# RestKit understand what to put in "pathPattern" and "keyPath" in RKResponseDescriptor

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I would like to use RestKit but I don't see how to write the pathPattern and the keyPath, where the json returns :

```html
{
   "photos": {
      "page": 1,
      "pages": 39594,
      "perpage": 10,
      "total": "395933",
      "photo": [
         {
            "id": "16766829152",
            "owner": "32546988@N00",
            "secret": "5b38b40c57",
            "server": "8744",
            "farm": 9,
            "title": "City box lights",
            "ispublic": 1,
            "isfriend": 0,
            "isfamily": 0
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The error :

> Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched

This is what I have now :

```
#define kBaseRESTURL            @"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method="
#define kSearchMethod           @"flickr.photos.search"

-(void)configureRestKit{

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kBaseRESTURL, kSearchMethod];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    RKObjectManager *manager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
    RKObjectMapping* photoMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Photo class]];
    [photoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"title"]];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDesc = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:photoMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"" keyPath:@"photos.photo" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
    [manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDesc];
}

-(void)loadCities : (void(^)(NSArray*))completion {
    [self configureRestKit];
    NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"api_key" : apiKey,
                                  @"tags" : @"cities",
                                  @"per_page" : @"10",
                                  @"format" : @"json",
                                  @"nojsoncallback" : @"1"
                                 };
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"" parameters:queryParams success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@" ");
          NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
      }];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the RK docs? And your URL doesn't actually have a path pattern as such as it uses query parameters for the key info

Comment: thanks, I edited my post, to show the error and the code I am using. Yes I read the doc, but I am confused about it : http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html the examples do not seem to match what I am trying to do with the flickr api?

Comment: Restkit isn't an ideal match for this use case as you will need to predicate the mapping on keypaths only and you'll likely get many spurious results. I'd use ObjectiveFlickr instead...

Comment: @Wain thanks, ok, could you tell me how the keyPath works in a general case? The key path would be "photos.photo"? So do you have an explanation why this would not work? The goal was to learn a bit more about Restkit, but I will have a look at objectiveFlickr.

Comment: Yes, that would be the keypath. The base URL should be `https://api.flickr.com/services/` and then the path pattern `rest/` with parameters for the method.

Comment: Thanks @Wain for the help, I will try to find an api where it is possible to use Restkit, I tried for flickr but the url returned in the log is `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?api_key=` so it does not match the url expected. Thanks anyway